# Tensorflow - Get Neighborhood of Pixel

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I'm trying to implement the loss function of the classic Image Colorization paper by Levin et al (2004) in Tensorflow/Keras:

[image: main_loss]

This is the weights equation (correlation between intensities):

[image: weights]

`y` is every neighboring pixel of `x` in a 3x3 window and `w` is the weight for each of these pixels.

The weights require computing the mean and variance for the neighborhood of every pixel.

I couldn't find a function that would allow me to write this loss function in a symbolic way, and I'm thinking I should write it in a loop where I calculate the `w` for each window.

How can I write this Loss function in Tensorflow In a Symbolic way or in loops?

Thanks so much.

EDIT: Here's the code I've come up for calculating the weights in Numpy:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

im = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('./Image.jpg', 0), (256, 256)) / np.float32(255.0)

M = 3
N = 3

# Split the image into 3x3 windows
windows = [im[x:x + M, y:y + N] for x in range(0, im.shape[0], M) for y in range(0, im.shape[1], N)]

# Calculate the correlation for each window
weights = [1 + np.corrcoef(tile) for tile in windows]
```

Comment: That sounds like a regular 2D convolution. Are these weights the same 3x3 matrix for every pixel neighborhood?

Comment: No, They are calculated as the correlation between the window pixels' intensities. I'll add the formula to the question in a moment.

Comment: What exactly is `I(x)`?

Comment: @sdcbr Intensity of grayscale image at point x. In numpy, that would be image[x] for a flattened image.

Comment: σ^2 is the same constant for every pixel, right?

Comment: Also I think I understand from your post that _N(x)_ does **not** include _x_, is that right?

Comment: @jdehesa σ^2 is for normalizing purposes. since we are calculating the correlation (and it is normalized between -1 and +1). I'll add a little more code to the question which I think is the right way to calculate the weights.
Also You're right, `N(x)` shouldn't include `x`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this code computes the value in your formula:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from itertools import product

SIGMA = 1.0

dtype = tf.float32
# Input images batch
img = tf.placeholder(dtype, [None, None, None])
img_shape = tf.shape(img)
img_height = img_shape[1]
img_width = img_shape[2]
# Compute 3 x 3 block means
mean_filter = tf.ones((3, 3), dtype) / 9
img_mean = tf.nn.conv2d(img[:, :, :, tf.newaxis],
                        mean_filter[:, :, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis],
                        [1, 1, 1, 1], 'VALID')[:, :, :, 0]
# Remove 1px border
img_clip = img[:, 1:-1, 1:-1]
# Difference between pixel intensity and its block mean
x_diff = img_clip - img_mean
# Compute neighboring pixel loss contributions
contributions = []
for i, j in product((-1, 0, 1), repeat=2):
    if i == j == 0: continue
    # Take "shifted" image
    displaced_img = img[:, 1 + i:img_width - 1 + i, 1 + j:img_height - 1 + j]
    # Compute difference with mean of corresponding pixel block
    y_diff = displaced_img - img_mean
    # Weights formula
    weight = 1 + x_diff * y_diff / (SIGMA ** 2)
    # Contribution of this displaced image to the loss of each pixel
    contribution = weight * displaced_img
    contributions.append(contribution)
contributions = tf.add_n(contributions)
# Compute loss value
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.squared_difference(img_clip, contributions))
```

The loss for the pixels along the image border is not computed, since in principle is not well defined in the formula, although you could make a few changes to take them into account if you want (change convolution to "'SAME'", pad where necessary, etc.).

Comment: Thanks so much... I'll try this out and inform you of the results. I really don't want to be greedy here but could you please show me how can I go about calculating this with batches of images? At the moment the only viable solution that comes to mind is to loop over the batch and at the end just take the mean of all of them.

Comment: @Cypher Yeah, I edited it to work for batches, it's just adding a couple of `:,` mostly

Answer (score 0):

this is a mean squared error of a 3 x 3 windows. right?
sounds like a GLCM matrix for texture analysis do you want apply this loss function for every 3x3 windows in the image?

I think that is better build the function that make this calculation with a Random weight in Numpy so after try build with TF to try a optimization.

Comment: I'm trying to implement the loss function of the classic Image Colorization paper by Levin et al. I do want to apply the weights for every 3x3 window in the image and if there is no other way I shall do what you suggested. But even considering that I have the `weights` in numpy, how can I implement the whole loss function? is `conv2d` appropriate for this ?